# XOR Doubly Linked List

Tags: c++, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

So I am trying to create a XOR Doubly Linked List as part of an exercise, but I keep getting a Segmentation fault on my removeFirst() function. I cannot figure out what is going wrong, does anybody have a clue?

This is what a node looks like:

```
class Node{

public:
    int data;
    Node *XOR;

};
```

I am using this function to calculate the XOR:

```
Node* returnXOR(Node *a, Node *b){
    return (Node*)((uintptr_t) (a) ^ (uintptr_t) (b));
}
```

This is my XOR Doubly Linked List class:

```
class XORDLL{

public:
Node *head;

XORDLL(){
    head = NULL;
}

void addFirst(int data){
    // Make a newNode pointer
    Node *newNode = new Node;

    // Set the variables
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->XOR = returnXOR(head, NULL);   

    // If the head is not empty set the XOR of the head to the next XOR the newNode
    if(head != NULL){
        head->XOR = returnXOR(newNode, returnXOR(head->XOR, NULL));
    }   

    // Set the newNode to the head 
    head = newNode;
}

void removeFirst(){
    // If head is equal to NULL, do nothing
    if(head == NULL){
        return;
    }
    // Store current head
    Node *tmp = head;

    // Set head equal to the next address
    head = returnXOR(tmp->XOR, NULL);
    head->XOR = returnXOR(tmp->XOR, tmp);


    // Delete tmp variable
    delete tmp;
}

void printList(){
    Node *current = head;
    Node *prev = NULL;
    Node *next;
    while(current != NULL){
        printf("%d ", current->data);
        next = returnXOR(current->XOR, prev);
        prev = current;
        current = next;           
    }
    printf("\n");
}
};
```

When I run this piece of code:

```
int main(){
    XORDLL l;
    l.addFirst(1);
    l.addFirst(2);
    l.addFirst(3);
    l.printList();
    l.removeFirst();
    l.printList();
    return 0;
}
```

This is the output:

3 2 1 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: You `returnXOR` function takes the raw memory address of two existing `Node`s, XORs the two raw memory addresses, and casts the result to a pointer to another `Node`. Unfortunately, the actual chance of the resulting memory address being a valid pointer to a `Node` are slim to none. Hence your crash. This is like taking the geographic longtitude and lattitude of two oasis in the African desert, exclusive-or the numeric longtitude/lattitude, travel to the new set of coordinates, and expecting to find a third oasis, there.

Comment: That was what I was thinking as well, but why does my printList() function work correctly, when using the same method.

Comment: Because, if you work out the math, that code always ends up visiting two valid nodes, then computing a NULL value (first XOR with null, XOR with 0, does nothing; and the next iteration XORs a memory address with itself, producing a NULL). You got very lucky there. BTW, `delete current, prev, next;` does not do what you think it does. It does not, I repeat, does not, delete three pointers. It seems that it would be a good idea to [spend a little bit more time reading a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Thanks for the information, I will have to sort that out for myself.

Comment: @JornvanderMaat `Node *newNode = (Node*) malloc (sizeof(Node));`  -- Why are you using `malloc` in a C++ program?  The code exhibits undefined behavior, since `Node` is not a POD type.  Your code does not construct `Node` objects -- in C++, `operator new` is used to dynamically construct types.  All `malloc` does is allocate bytes -- it does not construct objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `delete` the `malloc`'ed data. You need to `free` it instead, or use `new` instead of `malloc`.
Another bug is that you miss this line:

```
          void removeFirst(){
          // If head is equal to NULL, do nothing
          if(head == NULL){
              return;
          }
          // Store current head
          Node *tmp = head;

          // Set head equal to the next address
          head = returnXOR(tmp->XOR, NULL);
          head->XOR = returnXOR(head->XOR, tmp); <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Here

          // Free tmp variable
          free(tmp);
      }
```

Comment: Although this is also true, this is the least of the many, many problems with the shown code.

Comment: So I changed my code to get rid of the delete statements and used free, but I still get the same output.

Comment: Fixed another bug : )

Comment: There should be no call to `malloc` to begin with as it is totally wrong for the `Node` data type.  Thus you should not encourage usage of `free`.

Comment: I would say that there should be no calls to ```new``` either. But when you work on low level XORing pointers, I think ```malloc``` is not a big problem, as it's not really C++, it's just C.

Comment: The code exhibits undefined behavior, as `malloc` cannot be used on the `Node` type, as it is not a POD type.  So there is no `node->XOR` or `node->data` that properly exists that makes sense.

Comment: Changed my code again using new instead of malloc, makes no difference.

Comment: Hey, did you add the line from the code above? It works for me now. And if you switched to ```new```, did you change ```free``` to ```delete``` also?

Comment: @JornvanderMaat -- The point is that the code was wrong to begin with.  You cannot use `malloc` to instantiate or create non-POD types.

Comment: @grungegurunge I edited my code again to match yours and changed free to delete, but it is still not working. Am I missing something?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Ah I see, thanks for pointing that out, learned something new today :).

Comment: Yes, that works for me as well, must be a small error in my old code. Big thanks man :)